# Responsive design failed

Tags: html, css

I messed up the responsive design, if you minimize the browser smaller you'll see all the graphics are messed up. Is there a way to fix the graphics to stay where they should be if the browser size is smaller in css. http://www.magnixsolutions.com/dev/test/test.html

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using Bootstrap, which has tools for responsive design. The main thing is that you want to make sure to use **.row** classes and **spanx** column classes. See [How to use Twitter Bootstrap to Create a Responsive Website Design](http://www.onextrapixel.com/2012/11/12/how-to-use-twitter-bootstrap-to-create-a-responsive-website-design/) for more details.

Default grid is 12 columns. So your spans in a row should equal twelve. 
Your HTML should look something like this:

```
<div class="container">
     <div class="row">
          <div class="span8 image">
          </div>
          <div class="span4 containerForm">
          ...insert form here...
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Once you have the markup set properly, go to the CSS and start adding the @media queries as @watson mentions in his answer. Watch out, though. Bootsrap has a lot of default CSS set. You may have to override to get the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Media Queries [They are amazing!](http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/)